# DotNetOpenAuth Remember Me

Tags: dotnetopenauth

I am using OpenIdLogin (with OpenIdButton) control on my login page, I noticed that there are properties "RememberMe", "RememberMeText" and "RememberMeVisible".  However I can't get it to work, is there any example?

Say, after the user logged on to my site successufully via Google, the user then decided to close the browser. If the user launch a new browser again, the user should not have to type the login/password again, right?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

The Remember Me setting controls whether your own site keeps the user logged in, and presumably your site accepts OpenID and therefore has no password.  This setting does *not* control whether the user remains logged into the OpenID Provider, which likely uses a password.

Does that clear things up?  Or is the user having to log in using OpenID to your web site each time they open the browser?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Actually your last description was perfect, it behaves exactly like that:  the user have to log in using OpenID to my web site each time they open the browser (even with the RememberMe is checked)  Is there any specific web.config that may have missed?   I am using <authorization> <deny users="?"/> </authorization> in web.config, is that correct?

Comment: The behavior is like this:
1. On my web site Login page (OpenIdButton for Google), click Google
2. Google prompts username/password and enter them
3. Redirects back to my web site
4. Redirects to my "Landing Page" which is "DefaultUrl" parameter set in web.config <authenication><forms> tag
5. If I open a new TAB, and go directly to my Landing Page URL, it works, no need to re-enter password. However, If I close the browser, and open a new instance of the browser, it goes back to my LLogin page.

I tried it on both IE and Firefox..